# Deserialize JSON VB.NET

Tags: mysql, json, vb.net, web-services, serialization

I have got a big problem with deserializing JSON using VB.NET here is json sample:

```
[{"id":"1","numerTel":"48123123123","pozostalo":"50","reffer":"","email":""},{"id":"2","numerTel":"48123123123","pozostalo":"10","reffer":"","email":""}]
```

This is json made from mysql select * query, my vb app is connecting to php script who returns json array with data. How can i deserialize this and use every row, I want to parse each one row.
This is my actual code in vb:

```
Dim jsonResponse As String = "[{""id"":""1"",""numerTel"":""48123123123"",""pozostalo"":""50"",""reffer"":"""",""email"":""""},{""id"":""2"",""numerTel"":""48123123123"",""pozostalo"":""10"",""reffer"":"""",""email"":""""}]"
        Dim aba As MyC = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize(Of MyC)(jsonResponse)
```

And class:

```
 Public Class MyC
        Public Property id() As String
            Get
                Return m_id
            End Get
            Set
                m_id = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_id As String
        Public Property numerTel() As String
            Get
                Return m_numerTel
            End Get
            Set
                m_numerTel = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_numerTel As String
        Public Property pozostalo() As String
            Get
                Return m_pozostalo
            End Get
            Set
                m_pozostalo = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_pozostalo As String
        Public Property reffer() As String
            Get
                Return m_reffer
            End Get
            Set
                m_reffer = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_reffer As String
        Public Property email() As String
            Get
                Return m_email
            End Get
            Set
                m_email = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_email As String

    End Class
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: what is the "big problem"?  See: [Ask].  Generally, if you deserialize, you dont also have to parse.

Comment: You forgot the part where you describe the problem.  In what way is this code not working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That JSON doesn't represent an instance of `MyC`.  It represents an instance of `List(Of MyC)` (or any enumerable collection, really).

```
Dim aba As List(Of MyC) = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize(Of List(Of MyC))(jsonResponse)
```

Comment: for example:   get from id: 0 value reffer: